# GD library in a local instance of PHP running from Netbeans with xdebug

Tags: php, gd, netbeans-8

Normally I develop the PHP web sites using a text editor under Unix Apache `htdocs` directory and the sites using GD library just work "out of the box".

However for this new customer I was told to use their existing infrastructure with Netbeans as IDE running PHP **locally** on a Windows machine which does not have Apache. The site is ultimately going to be deployed under normal Apache/PHP environment where it does work fine.

Almost everything works fine locally, except that GD library, however enabled in `php.ini`, is not working. The code using GD fails with this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreate()
```

When I execute this file on the command line:

```
<?php //session_start();
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

its output includes GD module so it should be usable in the code:

```
C:\Program Files\PHP>php 1.php
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => ctype
    [4] => date
    [5] => filter
    [6] => hash
    [7] => iconv
    [8] => json
    [9] => mcrypt
    [10] => SPL
    [11] => pcre
    [12] => Reflection
    [13] => session
    [14] => standard
    [15] => mysqlnd
    [16] => tokenizer
    [17] => zip
    [18] => zlib
    [19] => libxml
    [20] => dom
    [21] => PDO
    [22] => bz2
    [23] => SimpleXML
    [24] => xml
    [25] => wddx
    [26] => xmlreader
    [27] => xmlwriter
    [28] => openssl
    [29] => curl
    [30] => fileinfo
    [31] => gd
    [32] => gettext
    [33] => gmp
    [34] => intl
    [35] => mbstring
    [36] => exif
    [37] => mysqli
    [38] => Phar
    [39] => pdo_mysql
    [40] => PDO_ODBC
    [41] => pdo_sqlite
    [42] => soap
    [43] => sockets
    [44] => sqlite3
    [45] => tidy
    [46] => xmlrpc
    [47] => xsl
    [48] => xdebug
)
```

But when I use the same function in a PHP page it does not include as many extensions:

```
Array ( [0] => Core [1] => bcmath [2] => calendar [3] => ctype [4] => date [5] => filter [6] => hash [7] => iconv [8] => json [9] => mcrypt [10] => SPL [11] => pcre [12] => Reflection [13] => session [14] => standard [15] => mysqlnd [16] => tokenizer [17] => zip [18] => zlib [19] => libxml [20] => dom [21] => PDO [22] => Phar [23] => SimpleXML [24] => xml [25] => wddx [26] => xmlreader [27] => xmlwriter [28] => cli_server [29] => xdebug )
```

Does it mean that something in `php.ini` is wrong and PHP works on command line, but not from Netbeans?

How can I enable GD library in this local environment?

Comment: Check the php.ini file that netbeans is using and make sure GD extension is enabled there.

Comment: Compare the output of `php --ini` at the command line with the output of `phpinfo()` in a web page. You'll probably find different INI files are being used.

Comment: In both cases it was the same INI. But the machine was restarted overnight and now everything is working. Not sure what it was and why though.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what happened, but after restarting the development machine everything suddenly worked. GD library loaded and is working fine. This may have something to do with the paths added to the PATH variable, maybe not, not sure.

Also I was struggling to get `xdebug` to work and stop on the breakpoints to no avail, but after restart it started working as well.